# Alterar linguagem de programação pro APK

Tags: java, ionic, app, google-play

Tenho um *App* na *PlayStore* que fiz utilizando o *ionic/cordova*, o *App* trava muito no smartphone e por esse motivo gostaria de criar um novo *App* do zero utilizando outra linguagem de programação, minha dúvida é se preciso criar um novo *App* na *PlayStore* ou só posso atualizar o *App* existente na *PlayStore*.

Comment: Nunca submeti nenhum app na PlayStore mas acredito que desde cumpra os requisitos abaixo não há nenhum problema em enviar este outro APK. 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=pt-BR

Answer (score 4):

Você pode sim atualizar o app. Na empresa em que trabalho hoje tinham apenas apps nativos para android e ios. Eu fiz híbridos com ionic e já atualizei em ambas plataformas. O que vc precisa é assinar o app com a mesma chave, nome de pacote, colocar uma versão acima que não terá problemas.